# Hide login console when load lightdm in Debian 10 Buster

Tags: debian, boot, openbox

I do debian minimal installation (no desktop on install), then add openbox, lightdm

```
apt-get install xorg openbox lightdm plymouth plymouth-themes
```

Also i hide grub menu and boot log messages. For it i do changes in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=0"
```

And (optional) use plymouth for show nice welcome image, but is still see **login tty** for less then second.

[image]

**How to hide it forever?**

Next image it is graphic login screen and it is ok for me, i know how to do auto login to hide it (same as described bellow)

[image]

P.S. When i install debian by default with desktop it load without login console, i just add "splash to grub settings".

Comment: Just to confirm, are you booting into a graphical environment or only a `tty`? Is this screen flashing before it then moves to a `lightdm` screen? Or is this the only login screen you need to get rid of?

Comment: I booting into a graphical environment lightdm. Yes i see flash for tty for less 1 second before graphic login form screen.

Comment: Can you reinstall lightdm and try the settings in my answer? `apt-get --purge remove lightdm` then `apt-get install lightdm` Verify that the lightdm service is enabled and add your user to the autologin group `groupadd -r autologin` `usermod -a user autologin` After than make sure that your configurations match what is in my post and comment back if those work or not.

Comment: I remove/add lightdm, add group, add user in group, made lightdm autologin for my user, but still see flash tty login

Comment: But i use this command usermod -aG usergroup username

Comment: Now i find small solution here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201321
I rename/remove/delete file in folder /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/

Comment: If what you found solves your problem I will remove my post and you can post an answer with what steps you took to solve your problem and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Now i find small solution here bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201321 I rename/remove/delete file in folder /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/

Not sure it is correct answer, but it work. Blinking cursor will stay, but it better then before

Comment: Add "vt.global_cursor_default=0" in /boot/cmdline.txt to get rid of the blinking cursor. (Tried it on RPI4)